# How to migrate Google App Engine from Python2.7 and DataStore to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My website was built using Google AppEngine, DataStore and Python2.7. It’s no longer working `This site can’t be reached`. I need to migrate to Python3 but I cannot identify which migration guide is best suited for me. Can anyone point me to the correct set? I would like to get it running as quickly as possible (I only have one hour a day to try to correct it -- I have an unrelated full-time job).

Comment: FYI - Google still supports Python2.7 and Datastore so your App should still work. There's probably something else preventing it from running. What does your log file say - go to ```console.cloud.google.com``` and then you click on ```logging```

Comment: The migration is a big task.  With one hour a day it will take a long time.

Comment: Check this out too https://www.gqueues.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-google-app-engine-python-2-to-python-3

Answer (score 1):

### Migration guide

Google provides a [step-by-step migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3) especially for AppEngine which you should follow.
Additionally, you will find lots of useful links there where you can read about the differences between Python 2 and Python 3 and the various **migration tools** available. Depending on your application those tools might even be able to do the migration **(more or less) automatically** for you.

> Please note: This is the migration guide for the AppEngine **standard environment**. If you don't know what you're using, you're most likely using the standard environment. While some steps will differ when using the **flexible environment**, migration of the code base as described in the guide will always be required.

### Video: Python 2 to 3: Migration Patterns & Motivators (Cloud Next '19)

There also is a [recording of a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bye7Rms0Vgw) by the Google Cloud Team on migration from Python 2 to 3 on YouTube.

### Still having issues?

Migrating from Python 2 to 3 is a well-known problem and there is tons of information available on the internet. Most likely the problems you face have already been solved by someone, so a Google search for a specific problem will likely give you a working solution.